# Get ID of EditText in Expandable ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, get-childitem

I'm using an Expandable ListView, I have a single EditText in Every Child Item.
**list_item.xml**:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/marks"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Obtained"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="142dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="60dp" />
```

There is a button on mainActivity, When the button is clicked, **I want to get Text of Every Child's EditText Entered by User**, 
I tried:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        edt=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.marks);
        String abc=edt.getText().toString();


        Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(),"This: "+ abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
```

But, **It works only when a group is Expanded**,(Toast shows me text which was readily present in EditText) Not when User hits the Button.

So, **How do I call getChildView method in Button Click?** *I don't know what arguments to pass when calling it in OnClick()*.
 OR

Maybe **a Hack will work**: When Button is Clicked, the expanded group is collapsed and expanded, So it will do what I want ? Maybe

Comment: I want to get Text of all child items. (Maybe in a loop)
But getView() has no loop, and it works just fine (else it only works when a group is expanded)

Comment: Well, It must be just one button,
And As u say, it's not a good approach, I think , the reason is: Some EditTexts might be null? Maybe. 
Then I can restrict the user, Button will work only when all fields are filled.
So, Please tell me, How to hold references and pass all values on One ButtonClick.

Comment: Order of getting the text should be as they are displayed.
I mean, Just the same as Toast is showing in above code.

Comment: User can enter in only one group during one session.
No Child's EditTexts would be >20.
So, I think, That's not much of memory management problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set ID of Every EditText Manually. This can be done in `getChildView()`.
Although It won't help you enter and Get Values From Child. **It's only for setting and getting ID**:

```
@Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                           boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

     if (convertView == null) {
              LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

     TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

     if(childPosition==0)//Original Id will be get only when First Child is being populated
{
          edt=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.marks);
    }
    edt.setId(childPosition); //here the ID will be same as childPosition i.e. 0,1,2...
    //Now You can get the ID by getID(id); //id can be 0,1,2...


    Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(),"This: "+ abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
        }
```